# Android: Button.setOnClickListener makes error during runtime

Tags: android

I'm making a very simple application which has to perform an action when the user clicks a button .I tried to do this with a OnClickListener but this is causing the program to stop during runtime . I have looked for different solutions but nothing could help me .
I found that the problem is situated at the line where I placed : Button.setOnClickListener

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(0x7f030000);

    Button b   = (Button) findViewById (0x7f05000a) ; 
    b.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) buttonL) ;



}
private OnClickListener buttonL  = new OnClickListener ( ) {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
//perform action}   
};
```

The error given by Logcat :

```
02-04 19:45:46.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27043): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-04 19:45:46.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27043): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{me.sms.smsReminder/me.sms.smsReminder.SmsReminderActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: me.sms.smsReminder.SmsReminderActivity$1
02-04 19:45:46.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27043):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1830)
02-04 19:45:46.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27043):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1851)
02-04 19:45:46.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27043):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
02-04 19:45:46.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27043):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
02-04 19:45:46.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27043):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-04 19:45:46.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27043):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
02-04 19:45:46.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27043):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
02-04 19:45:46.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27043):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-04 19:45:46.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27043):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-04 19:45:46.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27043):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-04 19:45:46.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27043):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-04 19:45:46.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27043):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-04 19:45:46.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27043): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: me.sms.smsReminder.SmsReminderActivity$1
02-04 19:45:46.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27043):    at me.sms.smsReminder.SmsReminderActivity.onCreate(SmsReminderActivity.java:28)
02-04 19:45:46.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27043):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
02-04 19:45:46.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27043):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1794)
02-04 19:45:46.101: E/AndroidRuntime(27043):    ... 11 more
```

Thanks  , Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have imported and are using the wrong listener, DialogInterface.OnClickListener. And so there's an error as your activity can't be cast into DialogInterface when the listener is triggered. Use View.OnClickListener and it should work.

Comment: Thanks , this was indeed the problem .

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the literal id of resources, you should be using:

`R.id.your_id`

R is a dynamically generated object that holds your resources.

For example, if you have a TextView defined in res/layout/main.xml as so:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Test Type"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/BLACK_TEXTCOLOR"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

You would reference this as:

`R.id.myTextView`

I would also recommend using an anonymous class for you click binding:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.id.myLayoutId);

    Button b   = (Button) findViewById (R.id.myButton) ; 
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //perform action
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setContentView(0x7f030000);

Button b   = (Button) findViewById (0x7f05000a) ;
```

These lines are strongly discouraged. use `R.id.buttonname' syntax to make your code less error-prone..
and can u tell line 28 for your code

To directly implement onclick functionality...

In layout of button , add another parameter

```
 android:onclick="functionName"
```

In java activity file..create a method like this then,

```
public void functionName(View v)
{
//Tasks to perform at on click event
}
```

Comment: You should never bind onclick events in the XML like that.  That defeats the purpose of creating reusable XML layouts!

Comment: @Jonathan: Whilst I agree in principle WRT reusable code, there is nothing wrong with binding onClick listeners in XML layout files in many situations.

Answer (score 0):

Can you doublecheck that buttonL is indeed an

> android.view.View. OnClickListener

and not a

> android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener

(check the import statements)

You could also put a breakpoint on b.setOnClickListener and inspect the value/type of buttonL

Answer (score 0):

You are using a DialogInterface.OnClickListener. You need to use a View.OnClickListener which requires the function onClick(View v), NOT onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1).

The error is a class cast exception when you try to cast the DialogInterface.OnClickListener into a View.OnClickListener as one is for dialogs and the latter is for buttons.

Also as mentioned above try to use R. Its generated for a reason so you should use it...